# python list of value to metric , how to?

Tags: python, data-binding, numpy, metrics

i'm not sure how can I word this

but I have a list of say

```
l = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

this is sorted and index so if I do l[0] => 'a'

i use `np.eye(5)` to get diagonal 1

```
array([[ 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.], 
[ 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.], 
[ 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.], 
[ 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.], 
[ 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

but my goal is to get something like ..

```
array([[ a., 0., 0., 0., 0.], 
[ 0., b., 0., 0., 0.], 
[ 0., 0., c., 0., 0.], 
[ 0., 0., 0., d., 0.], 
[ 0., 0., 0., 0., e.]])
```

=============update===================

np here is numpy library, sorry

import numpy as np

Comment: Are you using some sort of external library? What does `np` refer to?

Comment: @ChristianTernus: It's idiomatic to use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org) by starting off with `import numpy as np`.

Comment: What exactly is `a.` supposed to be? That's not a floating-point number, or a string, or any other kind of value in Python or bumpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the answer for @abarnert question you may think about using [SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org):

```
>>> from sympy import Symbol
>>> np.diag([Symbol(x) for x in ['a','b','c','d','e']])
array([[a, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, b, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, c, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, d, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, e]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 3):

So you want to create a diagonal array out of a vector, right? That's [`diag`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html#numpy.diag):

```
>>> l = ['a','b','c','d','e']  
>>> np.diag(l)
array([['a', '', '', '', ''],
       ['', 'b', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', 'c', '', ''],
       ['', '', '', 'd', ''],
       ['', '', '', '', 'e']],
      dtype='|S1')
```

Or, if those are meant to be variables rather than strings:

```
>>> a, b, c, d, e = 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.
>>> l = [a, b, c, d, e]
>>> np.diag(l)
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  3.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.]])
```